# Disabling OneDrive on Scheduled PowerShell Script

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012-r2, scheduled-task

I need to disable OneDrive via a scheduled task in a PowerShell script. The command works when executed directly in PowerShell but not when executed via scheduling. The scheduling was done with the same user that runs OneDrive, and I tested it with and without administrator permission.

```
& "C:\Users\LocalAdmin\AppData\Local\Microsoft\OneDrive\OneDrive.exe" /shutdown
```

Comment: I think you are making this more complicated and less reliable than it needs to be. OneDrive is easily and permanently disabled via GPO and or the registry: https://www.petenetlive.com/KB/Article/0001328